# Socket.io find rooms the client has joined

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

Is there a way to find what rooms a client joined?

The situation I am trying to solve is the following: people can join different rooms, but I want to notify people in the room if the person leaves. I know that I have to use on `disconnect` event and emit the message to all people in that room, but I can not find a way to know what rooms the person is in.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
   client.on('disconnect', function() {
      // ...
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.rooms` would do the trick.

**Note:** Keep in mind that according to the [docs](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room),

> For your convenience, each socket automatically joins a room identified by this id.

So by default each socket is joined to at least one room.

Comment: I'm using socket.io 1.1 and this answer doesn't work. It seems client.rooms is already emptied by the time the `disconnect` event gets fired.

Comment: @lastoneisbearfood Good point! They changed its logic in deed. From the [new-in-socket.io-1.1-article](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-1-1-0/#more-390): `Fixed room removal logic when leaving a room, props`